# What status error to return when request fails a server logic (if-else condition)

Tags: html, rest

I have a server-side logic that will rollback the SQL transaction if the object fails an if-else condition.

Server logic:
My API route will send an evaluation report to a job client, but will check first through an if-else condition if the job first is completed (through a select query).

My question is: What error code will I return to the user? I'm currently using Error 401, but not sure if it's correct or appropriate.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, what does it represent exactly? An expected failure? An unexpected failure? Was it the client’s fault (4xx) or the server's internal problem (5xx)?

Comment: It was an expected failure. I'm just putting safety checks on routes so that say, they did click the Send button intentionally while knowing that the job is not yet completed, it will send the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fetching a report, but the report doesn't exist (yet) because the process that generates the report is not yet completed, that sounds like a `404 Not Found` to me.

Alternatively, if *something else* needs to be done by a client before the report is available, `409 Conflict` might also be a good fit.

`401` is definitely not.

Comment: Alright, got it. I read Error 409 now and it fits. Thank you!